# Recommended method to load application drop down / look ups / reference data in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hsqldb

What method do you recommend to load application data such as list of medications or countries or states or  other typically reference data into a database?

Currently I'm using spring and an in memory database (HSQL) however, I will move to a more traditional relational database.

I'm relatively new to spring/java so don't assume to0 much.

In .net I typically had a cmd script to create and reload the database wheneverI needed..but that might be difficult to do with an in memory database and I also wonder if there a typical spring/java means of getting this done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dbunit.org/ is a good option.